# Idiomatic handling of region boundaries while modifying its content

Tags: region

I want to write a function to indent SQL embedded in a markdown file.

It seems to make sense to use the region for this.

However, the looping form I am using is:

```
(defun rr/sql-indent-region (beginning end)
  (interactive "r")
  (while (< (point) end)
     ...
     (forward-word 1)
```

The `...` is adding `\n` characters after SELECT, FROM, GROUP BY etc, so that the block I started with no longer ends at END.

As I write this, I guess one option would be to copy the region to a temporary buffer, and use `(< (point) (point-max))`.  Is that the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

There are several common approaches you could take.  I don't think there's any single "best" option in general.

Using a temporary buffer is entirely reasonable.  Buffers are cheap to create.  `insert-buffer-substring` is useful here.

You can also just use *narrowing* in the current buffer, in which case `(point-max)` will be the end of the narrowed region, just like in the temporary buffer.  <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Narrowing`.  Note also `eobp`.

Finally you could use a *marker* for the end position, which will dynamically adjust itself when the text before the marker is modified.  <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Markers`

In your case I would suggest using narrowing, but experimenting with all three options could be useful.

https://github.com/alex-hhh/emacs-sql-indent may be of interest to you as well.

Comment: Another option is to iterate from end to beginning.  In the current case it's probably not a good choice, but in many other cases it's a fine option.